# DC electromagnet strength: voltage or current?

Tags: current, dc, dc-dc-converter, electromagnetism, electromagnetic

Is the strength of a DC electromagnet more determined by current or voltage?

For example: if I had one battery at a fixed output that I could step up or down, would it be better to have a higher voltage or current?

I don't want loads of equations as this doesn't have to be accurate. I just need to know if I should step up or down my power?

P.S: and do you have a recommendation where I can find out how to create a circuit about stepping up or down DC. I've had a look around but I don't know what is best or now as this is not something I usually do.

Comment: Go and read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet  Note how the magnetic field is determined by ... (you fill it in). Suppose I have a 9V battery, there is 9 V but does it have magnetic field ? Now connect an electromagnet to the 9V battery, what happens ? Voltage and current are also related by Ohm's law so more voltage means more current. But it is actually the current determining the field.

Comment: It's determined by current times the number of turns, and more turns requires more voltage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: Current. The strength of the magnetic field depends on the current that flows in a linear fashion - Double the current, double the magnetic field. Since the resistance of the conductor is the thing that determines the current, you need more voltage to have that current.

Comment: Thanks man! So you're saying if I step up the voltage then the current output from the battery should increase accordingly it the resistance? So to have a stronger electromagnet I should increase the voltage in? Or am i completely wrong here and should lower the voltage in boost the current?

Comment: You are correct - you need to increase the voltage to increase the current. This goes by Ohm's law: R=V/I, where R is resistance, V is voltage and I is current. In this case, we rewrite it as I=V/R. As R is fixed, we see that for more current, we need more Voltage. Keep in mind, however, that more current will also lead to more power dissipated in the coil, and thus more heat. Most coils have a maximum rating, make sure to not exceed that rating.

Comment: Brilliant! Learn something new every day! :)

Comment: @TorinClark - But. Big but. If you increase the voltage/current, you will increase the power dissipated by the magnet. And if you double the voltage you will increase power by a factor of 4. Since the magnet has lots of turns stacked on each other the interior of the magnet can get hotter than the outside, and you can wind up cooking the insulation. Just be careful and don't go hog-wild with cranking things up. Even better, if you've bought the magnet find the data sheet and see what it's rated for - and believe the data sheet.

Answer (score 4):

Magnetic field strength is determined by ampere-turns (current multiplied by number of turns). The voltage that results is a consequence of the resistance under static conditions (indeed, if the wire has no resistance there is no voltage, and therefore no power required to maintain the field).

However, under normal (non-superconducting) conditions, and given a certain cross-sectional area of window on the bobbin to wind your coil you can wind the coil with thicker or thinner wire and accommodate different voltages- and the power required will work out roughly the same for the same magnetic field strength regardless of the voltage you design it for.

You can change voltage up or down with a boost or buck regulator switching. Somewhat more complex regulators can go up or down to change, say, +3-4V to +3.5V. The latter are called buck-boost regulators. Thousands of such chips and associated circuits are available.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If you're rewinding the magnet to suit the different voltages you'll find it doesn't make any difference at all. What matters is turns * current = Ampere Turns.

A higher voltage will let you push current through more turns of wire - they have to be thinner wire to occupy the same space so the resistance will increase as the square of the number of turns.  So as P = I^2*R both versions will consume the same power and produce the same field strength in Ampere-Turns.